# How to prevent file downloaded via response.outputStream to be saved on server?

Tags: grails, groovy

When downloading the file via a link in grails page, following controller is working. However, somehow the downloaded file is also saved in my project structure web-app. Right now, it is running in my local host. So when moved to production, this will start saving the file in server as well. Is there any way to allow a regular download to client's machine but prevent or clean the download to server?

```
File uploadedInBackEndToBeDownloadedFromFrontEnd = fetchTheFileFromBackEnd() // some custom method
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;")
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", " uploadedInBackEndToBeDownloadedFromFrontEnd  ; filename=\"${ uploadedInBackEndToBeDownloadedFromFrontEnd  .name}\"")
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "$ uploadedInBackEndToBeDownloadedFromFrontEnd  .size()}")
response.outputStream <<  uploadedInBackEndToBeDownloadedFromFrontEnd .getBytes()
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It certainly seems that `fetchTheFileFromBackEnd()` is saving the file somewhere..

Comment: Well maybe syntax issue here: 

`response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${uploaded.name}")`